# Multi-page subfigures using the subfigure package

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm trying to create figure that contains many subfigures and I want it to span multiple pages. I'm using the `subfigure` package to create my figure:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{figure}[!hbp]
\begin{center}
    \subfigure[caption1]{\includegraphics[width = 12cm]{img/plot.png}}
   \subfigure[caption2]{\includegraphics[width = 12cm]{img/plot2.png}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

After some googling I found a solution but using another package called `subfig`. However when I tried to use it, I get an error. I get the error just the moment I put the declaration to use `\usepackage{subfig}`.

Here is the error:

[image]

So I either need a solution to work with `subfigure` or a solution to work with `subfig`.

Comment: The subfig and subfigure packages are not compatible. By the way, the `subfigure` package is deprecated; use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package. Please provide more information regarding the multi-page nature of the material containing the subfigures. E.g., do you want the material to be contained in a single `figure` environment? How should the subfigures be numbered: Consecutively as in (a), (b), ..., or in some other style?

Comment: Two more comments. First, judging from the screenshot you've posted, it looks like you're using TeXLive2012 -- any chance you can upgrade your system to TeXLive2014? Second, the screenshot also seems to indicate that you're loading the `caption` package. If that's the case, ditch the `subfig` (or `subfigure`) package and load the `subcaption` package instead. Then, search for "`ContinuedFloat`" on this site and you'll find several postings about making a `figure` (or `table`) extend across more than one page.

Comment: A float (figure) cannot span more than one page, so you will need to pack your subfigures into multiple figures, one per page.  Second, there is nothing \subfigure does than cannot be done using tabular.

Comment: @Mico I also heard that `subfig` is deprecated, and now I'm confused which to use! I have one context (figure) that have subfigures (a,b,c). I want the subfigures to be placed either vertically one after the other, or next to each other ... as space allows.

Comment: @Mico I removed the `subfigure` and now it compiles with `subfig`. I was using TeXShop but now I switched to TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to stack these vertically, you might as well use a separate figure for each image.  (I had to shrink it a little to fit 2 per page.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcounter{subfig}[figure]
\newcommand{\subcap}[1]% caption
{\refstepcounter{subfig}(\alph{subfig}) {#1}\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering\subcap{caption1}\includegraphics[width = 10cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering\subcap{caption2}\includegraphics[width = 10cm]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a possible \contcaption, but for multipage figures with a single caption you really need a new environment (not figure).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\contcaption}[0]% no arguments
{\@makecaption\fnum@figure{continued}}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Nice solution! I wondering how and where to add main caption? For example, if there are three page of subcaptions how you know to which figure belongs subfigures on the first or second page? For such a cases memoir (for other packages I don't know) provide `contcaption` (continuation of caption) which doesn't increment caption's counter.

Comment: @Zarko - You can use \captionof{figure}{...} from the caption package, and I added a \contcaption fo the answer.  The memoir \contcaption would reset the subfig counter each time.  Anyway, where are you going to put it?  Every figure?  In the header?

Comment: Your are right about resetting `subcaption` counter by `contcaption`. It is useful only if you manually adequate preset `subcaption` counter in each figure with `contcaption``